# Using of iOS framework in tvOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, tvos

Is it any way for using framework, that was build for iOS, to use it in tvOS app? In our framework we are using third-part framework with this problem. When we connect our framework to any app we have following:

- Simulator compiled and running well, but warning said "ld: warning: URGENT:  .... (Srt.o), building for tvOS, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64. Note: This will be an error in the future.
- If trying to launch with real tvOS device - this warning turning to Error.

  And everything fixed, if we are not using that third-party library, but we need it. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose that your 3rd party framework is not open source. Else built it yourself for tvOS. The other option is to ask the framework provider for a tvOS version of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

No, tvOS is a different platform and is not binary-compatible with iOS.